# how to create next and previous month menu link in calendar in drupal 7

Tags: 7, commerce, datetime

how to create next and previous menu link in calendar in drupal 7

### Next month >>                              << Previous month

```
             ---- calendar area ----
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar)** Module.

From project page..

> This module will display any Views date field in calendar formats, including CCK date fields, node created or updated dates, etc. **Switch between year, month, and day views. Back and next navigation is provided for all views**. Lots of the Calendar functionality comes from the Date module, so any time you update the Calendar module you should be sure you also update to the latest version of the Date module at the same time.

Hope this will help you.